# jQuery slider stop on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover

I'm currently working on a small jQuery element but having some trouble with clearInterval.

I made a jsFiddle with an example what I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/eWTSu/

As you can see it rotates fine but when I hover over a navigation button the rotation does not stop. Also there's a problem with the order of the rotation. The rotation goes div1, div2, div3, div4 and repeat. But when I hover of the third button while the rotation is on the first div it loads the second div on top of the third.

Does anyone have a good tip for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eWTSu/11/)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.greenC, .blueC, .orangeC').hide();

    $('.nav li').hover(function () {
        var liClass = $(this).attr('class');

        $('.slider').hide();
        $('.' + liClass + 'C').show();
    });

    (function () {
        var interval_function = function () {
            jQuery('#header_slider > div:first')
                .hide()
                .next()
                .show()
                .end()
                .appendTo('#header_slider');
        };

        var interval = setInterval(interval_function, 1000);

        $('.nav li').hover(function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, function () {
            interval = setInterval(interval_function, 1000);
        });
    }());
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and addition to my code but there is still a small problem with the code though. If the slider is on the blue div and you hover on the yellow list item the rotating does stop and the div turns to yellow which is fine.

But when you remove the mouse from the yellow list item the yellow div stays shown which results in having two divs shown. Also the rotation does not take that in account. The next div should be green (because you hover over yellow) but it just continue it's own rotation.

Do you happen to have a idea on how to fix that?

Comment: So it's all in the variables? I really got the get into that then. Great, thanks for your great help!